# Using sed to remove a block of text

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I have a block of text that looks like this:

```
    <!-- BOF CLEAN -->
... a bunch of stuff 
    <!-- EOF CLEAN -->
```

I'd like to remove this entire block.  What's the sed command?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
$ cat text 
abc
    <!-- BOF CLEAN -->
... a bunch of stuff
    <!-- EOF CLEAN -->
def
$ sed '/<!-- BOF CLEAN -->/,/<!-- EOF CLEAN -->/d' text 
abc
def
```

I cannot explain it any better than [Sed One-Liners Explained, Part III: Selective Deletion of Certain Lines and Special Applications](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-three/).

Comment: SED deleted my file!! I did `sed '/^0.*$/d' s1d13700.c` which spit  the correct result to the console, then I did `sed '/^0.*$/d' s1d13700.c >s1d13700.c` to overwrite the original file with the result, and the file ended up completely empty!

Comment: @Zom-B What happens in `sed ... s1d13700.c >s1d13700.c` is that the shell first creates a new empty file `s1d13700.c` before running sed, thus overwriting your input file with the same name. Use `sed -i.original ... s1d13700.c` to change the file in-place and create a back-up of the original file as `s1d13700.c.original`.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus technically, the shell deleted (truncated) your file, and logically, you deleted your file. Note that `sed -i` is a GNU (non-POSIX) extension, as far as I remember

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to the book!

Answer (score 11):

To remove all the text starting from and including  `<!-- BOF CLEAN -->` and ending at and including `<!-- EOF CLEAN -->`, use following sed command:

```
sed -i '/<!-- BOF CLEAN -->/,/<!-- EOF CLEAN -->/d' file_name;
```

Reference: [Delete text or paragraph between two sections using sed](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/sed-howto-remove-lines-paragraphs/)

Answer (score 0):

These days I am using the `/s` modifier to do this.  I noticed no one mentioned that.   I use markup with is free of spaces too like

```
    {bof-nf}
... a bunch of stuff 
    {eof-nf}
```

So for example, to remove this block, use

`$newcontent = preg_replace("/\{bof-nf\}(.*)\{eof-nf\}\\n/s", "", $newcontent);`

To keep the block but remove the tags, use

```
$newcontent = preg_replace("/\{bof-nf\}.*\\n/", "", $newcontent);
$newcontent = preg_replace("/\{eof-nf\}.*\\n/", "", $newcontent);
```