# How to remove a text block from a file with bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I have file of bind config with following config:

```
zone "domain1.com" {
        type master;
        file "masters/domain1.com";
        allow-transfer {
                dnscontroller_acl;
        };
};


zone "domain2.com" {
        type master;
        file "masters/domain2.com";
        allow-transfer {
                dnscontroller_acl;
        };
};

zone "domain3.com" {
        type master;
        file "masters/domain3.com";
        allow-transfer {
                dnscontroller_acl;
        };
};

zone "domain4.com" {
        type master;
        file "masters/domain4.com";
        allow-transfer {
                dnscontroller_acl;
        };
};
```

How to remove zone config (start from `zone` filename and end of `};`) from file with help of bash?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945621/using-sed-to-remove-a-block-of-text

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/6945621/ - can not use it in cause end of block `};` is not unique

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `sed` to remove the config for a given zone:

```
sed '/^zone "domain4.com" {$/,/^};/d' file
```

If you want a script that can take a zone as an argument, just add the she-bang and the argument:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed '/^zone "'"$1"'" {$/,/^};/d' file
```

Comment: For fellow SED newbs out there.. I was able to get this to work for me by assuming: `sed '/^STARTSTR-MARK$/,/^ENDSTR-MARK/d' file` based on this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is well ordered, you could use `awk` with automatic record- and field separation:

```
awk '
  BEGIN { RS = ORS = "\n\n"; FS="\n" } 
  $1 !~ /domain3/
' file
```

Removes zone where the first line contains "domain3".

Comment: This is a good approach, but perhaps cleaner to write `awk '$2 !~ /domain3/' RS= file`

Comment: Yes and no, you also need to set `ORS='\n\n`, otherwise whitespace is removed from between the records.