# Remove mutiline string after equal sign

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to get IAM policies from AWS and add it to a text file in the below specific format. I want to delete everything after policy= in the file before end of the "}" bracket.

This is the text file sample I have. But the original file can have multiple instances of example_policy in the same file.

```
"example1_policy" {
    name="example"
    policy=jsonencode(
        {
            Statement=[
                {
                    Action=[
                        s3:*
                    ]
                    Effect="Allow"
                },
            ]
            Version="2012-10-17"
        }
    )
}
"example2_policy" {
    name="example2"
    policy=jsonencode(
        {
            Statement=[
                {
                    Action=[
                        s3:*
                    ]
                    Effect="Allow"
                },
            ]
            Version="2012-10-17"
        }
    )
}
"example3_policy" {
    name="example3"
    policy=jsonencode(
        {
            Statement=[
                {
                    Action=[
                        s3:*
                    ]
                    Effect="Allow"
                },
            ]
            Version="2012-10-17"
        }
    )
}
```

Expected Output:

```
"example1_policy" {
    name="example1"
    policy=
}
"example2_policy" {
    name="example2"
    policy=
}
"example3_policy" {
    name="example3"
    policy=
}
```

or

```
"example1_policy" {
    name="example1"
    policy=<placeholder>
}
"example2_policy" {
    name="example2"
    policy=<placeholder>
}
"example3_policy" {
    name="example3"
    policy=<placeholder>
}
```

As per @Wiktor's comment I tried out this command

```
sed -i '/policy=/,/^\s*)\s*$/d' test.txt
```

Output: policy= should remain intact.

```
"example_policy" {
    name="example"
}
```

Comment: There is just one line with `)` on it, you might want to leverage that fact and write a solution like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945621/using-sed-to-remove-a-block-of-text).

Comment: I tried this - sed -i '/(/,/)/d' test.txt, it removed the policy= as well

"example_policy" {
    name="example"
}

Comment: With GNU sed, it is just `sed -i '/policy=/,/^\s*)\s*$/d' test.txt`

Comment: Yes, I use GNU sed and got the same output. Removed the policy= as well

Comment: Please add the attempt to the question and provide the expected output.

Comment: Sorry, so what should be the expected output? You supplied [my  suggestion output](https://ideone.com/uqDZH3).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I want to remove everything after policy= and not policy= itself. Updated the question with expected outputs as well. Thanks!

Comment: Try `sed '/policy=/,/^\s*)\s*$/{/policy=/!d};s/\(policy=\).*/\1<placehlder>/' file`

Comment: Perfect! That Worked! Can you please add that as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following GNU sed command:

```sh
sed -i '/policy=/,/^\s*)\s*$/{/policy=/!d};s/\(policy=\).*/\1<placehlder>/' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/WbqZgH). *Details*:

- `/policy=/,/^\s*)\s*$/` - finds blocks of lines between a line with `policy=` and a line that contains only a `)` char enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `{/policy=/!d}` - prevents the first line in the found block to be removed and removed the other line(s)
- `s/\(policy=\).*/\1<placehlder>/` - replaces all after `policy=` with `<placeholder>`.

**If there is a need to match `policy=`, then any chars up to `(` and then *up to the next balanced `)` char***, you can use `perl` command like

```perl
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/^(\h*policy=)[^()]*(\((?:[^()]++|(?2))*\))/$1<placehlder>/gm' file
```

*Details*:

- `-0777` - read the file into a single string so that line breaks and the lines
- `-i` - inline file change
- `^` - start of a line (due to `m` flag)
- `(\h*policy=)` - Group 1 (`$1`): zero or more horizontal whitespaces
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `(\((?:[^()]++|(?2))*\))` - Group 2 (for recursion): `\(` - a `(` char, `(?:[^()]++|(?2))*` - zero or more sequences of one or more chars other than `(` and `)` or the whole Group 2 pattern recursed, and `\)` matches a `)` char
- `$1<placehlder>` - the replacement is Group 1 + `<placeholder>` string

**See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/I4njC9) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cT0wtX/1)**:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='"example1_policy" {
    name="example"
    policy=jsonencode(
        {
            Statement=[
                {
                    Action=[
                        s3:*
                    ]
                    Effect="Allow"
                },
            ]
            Version="2012-10-17"
        }
    )
}
"example2_policy" {
    name="example2"
    policy=jsonencode(
        {
            Statement=[
                {
                    Action=[
                        s3:*
                    ]
                    Effect="Allow"
                },
            ]
            Version="2012-10-17"
        }
    )
}
"example3_policy" {
    name="example3"
    policy=jsonencode(
        {
            Statement=[
                {
                    Action=[
                        s3:*
                    ]
                    Effect="Allow"
                },
            ]
            Version="2012-10-17"
        }
    )
}'
perl -0777 -pe 's/^(\h*policy=)[^()]*(\((?:[^()]++|(?2))*\))/$1<placehlder>/gm' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
"example1_policy" {
    name="example"
    policy=<placehlder>
}
"example2_policy" {
    name="example2"
    policy=<placehlder>
}
"example3_policy" {
    name="example3"
    policy=<placehlder>
}
```

Comment: this won't work if you have additional `(` characters anywhere in the middle of your policy

Comment: @rudolfovic Not a problem, a short `perl -0777 -i -pe 's/^(\h*policy=)[^()]*(\((?:[^()]++|(?2))*\))/$1<placehlder>/gm' file` meets your requirements. However, even this is not 100% safe if we assume there can be `(` and `)` inside the `policy=...)` block.

Comment: That’s exactly what I meant, an infinite number of braces isn’t supported by regex, that’s why I went for a python solution

Comment: @rudolfovic an infinite number of braces/parentheses/etc. **IS** supported by regex, see my second solution, `perl -0777 -i -pe 's/^(\h*policy=)[^()]*(\((?:[^()]++|(?2))*\))/$1<placehlder>/gm' file` - see the [online demo](https://ideone.com/I4njC9). BTW, Python `re` regex flavor does not support recursion, unlike PCRE/Perl.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this quite easily in Python since you have state:

```py
def clean(s, pattern='policy='):
  pre, post = s.split(pattern)
  harmony = True
  quote = False
  braces = 0
  for i, char in enumerate(post):
    if harmony and char == '\n':
      return f'{pre}{pattern}{post[i:]}'
    if not quote:
      if char == '(':
        braces += 1
      elif char == ')':
        braces -= 1
      elif char in ('"', "'"):
        quote = char
      harmony = braces == 0
    elif quote == char:
      quote = False
```

This would even ignore braces that are enclosed in strings (both " and ' strings).

So, this version works on trickier strings too:

```
"example_policy" {
    name="example"
    policy=jsonencode(
        {
            Statement=[
                {
                    Action=[
                        s3:*
                    ]
                    Effect="Al)l'ow"
                },
            ]
            Version='"2012-10)-17"'
        }
    )
}
```

You can easily extend this to support other types of braces or quotation. The only difference is that you need to use counters for braces since the opening and the closing characters are different, while for quotations you just need to add extra characters to the matching list - since everything else within the quotation is ignored, you just need to remember which character the quote was opened with.

Doing this with regexes would be tricker since they only support finite brace nesting.

To remove multiple policies within the same string we need to define a helper function:

```py
def clean(s):
  harmony = True
  quote = False
  braces = 0
  for i, char in enumerate(s):
    if harmony and char == '\n':
      return s[i:]
    if not quote:
      if char == '(':
        braces += 1
      elif char == ')':
        braces -= 1
      elif char in ('"', "'"):
        quote = char
      harmony = braces == 0
    elif quote == char:
      quote = False
  return s
```

And then the main function that will apply the "cleaning helper" to each individual chunk:

```py
def clean_all(s, pattern='policy='):
  head, *tail = s.split(pattern)
  return f'{head}{pattern}{pattern.join(clean(part) for part in tail)}'
```

Comment: I could use it, but I want to update the entire file and not pass it as an argument. There could be 100's of policies in a file. Would really appreciate if you could provide an example on how to achieve the same with a file.

Comment: please be more specific - do you have multiple instances of `"example_policy" {...}` within one file / string or do you have multiple instances of `policy=` within one `"example_policy" {...}`? please include an appropriate complete example in your question that would cover your general case so that correct solutions could be suggested from the beginning

Comment: I did mention that I am trying to get IAM policies not just one policy. Sorry for not being clear. Updated the question. Thanks!